# Npm install produces error Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use, code --version produces vs code version, added it to path

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm

Trying to run ionic, capacitor, react project after long time again on windows machine, before everything worked good, now first it asked me for python, so i installed it and added it to path, then it asks me for VS Code, I'm working in VS Code, added it as well to path, but still getting error "Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use", even though i run npm install comand from VS Code and also entering code --version gets me vs code version

```
PS C:\Dev\pianoNew\PianoTrainerNewPlayer\osmd-player-react-master> code --version
1.70.1
6d9b74a70ca9c7733b29f0456fd8195364076dda
x64
```

This is complete error messsage

```
 PS C:\Dev\pianoNew\PianoTrainerNewPlayer\piano> npm install
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated @fortawesome/fontawesome@1.1.8: This package is deprecated. See https://git.io/fNCzJ for information about upgrading.
    npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: LINK REMOVED
    npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.19: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated superagent@4.1.0: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at <https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases>.
    npm WARN deprecated ionic@5.4.16: The Ionic CLI now uses ✨ @ionic/cli ✨ for its package name!  https://twitter.com/ionicframework/status/1223268498362851330
    npm WARN deprecated @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands@5.0.13: This package is deprecated. See https://git.io/fNCzJ for information about upgrading.
    npm WARN deprecated @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid@5.0.13: This package is deprecated. See https://git.io/fNCzJ for information about upgrading.
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path C:\Dev\pianoNew\PianoTrainerNewPlayer\piano\node_modules\cap
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at "C:\Python106\python.exe"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Dev\pianoNew\PianoTrainerNewPlayer\piano\node_modules\cap
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\eloi0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-15T03_33_16_265Z-debug-0.log
    PS C:\Dev\pianoNew\PianoTrainerNewPlayer\piano> code .
    PS C:\Dev\pianoNew\PianoTrainerNewPlayer\piano> code --version
    1.70.1
    6d9b74a70ca9c7733b29f0456fd8195364076dda
    x64
    PS C:\Dev\pianoNew\PianoTrainerNewPlayer\piano>
```